# How to skip memory reading while debugging my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

If I set a break point on my app , after a few clicks on `step over` I get something like this:

```
0x36589606:  mov    r0, r4
0x36589608:  mov    r2, r6
0x3658960a:  movs   r3, #4
0x3658960c:  mov    r1, r10
0x3658960e:  blx    0x369e4aa4                ; symbol stub for: -[_UIHostedTextServiceSession dismissTextServiceAnimated:]
0x36589612:  mov    r1, r8
0x36589614:  mov    r5, r0
```

How can I skip it back to my code? (step over stays in the memory readings..)
Thanks

Comment: Keep pressing it you will come back to the code once all assmbly code ends.

Comment: but sometimes it takes forever. I want to avoid that.

Comment: it shows every step, even if you go for `step out` it won't go to the code, it will go to next method/function inside the assembly code.

Comment: So there's no way around that?

Comment: AFAIK, I will say **NO**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to "step out", that is the button with the up arrow, on your left side of the debugger window. You might have to click it a few times but it will definitely be less than stepping through code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just tried it. It takes a few clicks but then it takes me out of the code completely and returns to `Play` mode

Comment: Hmm, it shouldn't, you should not go back to play mode unless you hit play. Unless you clicked to step out even past your "code". So the idea is to use that step out to get you out of apple/assembly code but then when you are back into your code, then you go back to just using "step" - typing "s" in your debugger command line